# Expressing fomula in terms of Tan instead of Cos and Sin

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I have the following formula in Mathematica:

$$\frac{c \rho  S \left(\text{Z0} \cos \left(\frac{5 \pi  (2 n+1) x}{6 a+10 L}\right)+i c \rho  S \sin \left(\frac{5 \pi  (2 n+1) x}{6 a+10 L}\right)\right)}{c \rho  S \cos \left(\frac{5 \pi  (2 n+1) x}{6 a+10 L}\right)+i \text{Z0} \sin \left(\frac{5 \pi  (2 n+1) x}{6 a+10 L}\right)}$$

Code:

```
(c S \[Rho] (Z0 Cos[(5 (1 + 2 n) \[Pi] x)/(6 a + 10 L)] + 
   I c S \[Rho] Sin[(5 (1 + 2 n) \[Pi] x)/(6 a + 10 L)]))/(
c S \[Rho] Cos[(5 (1 + 2 n) \[Pi] x)/(6 a + 10 L)] + 
 I Z0 Sin[(5 (1 + 2 n) \[Pi] x)/(6 a + 10 L)])
```

I would like to manipulate it in Mathematica by dividing the numerator and denominator by $\cos \left(\frac{5 \pi  (2 n+1) x}{6 a+10 L}\right)$ so that I get the same expression in terms of two Tan functions. Is there an easy way to do this? I've had a good look in the docs and can't seem to find anything!

Comment: Almost the same as Nasser's answer, but expressed in another form: `expression /. Sin[x_] :> Hold[Tan[x]] Cos[x] // Simplify // ReleaseHold`, so we introduce `Tan` but keep it from evaluation when `Cos` is cancelled during `Simplify`.

Answer (score 4):

I like to use [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) when possible.  For example, this seemed to work well in this case:

```
FullSimplify[expr, 
 ComplexityFunction -> 
  Function[e, 
   100 Count[e, _Cos | _Sin | E, {0, Infinity}] - 
    10 Count[e, _Tan, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e]]]
```

$$\frac{c \rho  S \left(\text{Z0}+i c \rho  S \tan \left(\frac{5 \pi  (2 n+1) x}{6 a+10
   L}\right)\right)}{c \rho  S+i \text{Z0} \tan \left(\frac{5 \pi  (2 n+1) x}{6 a+10 L}\right)}$$

Answer (score 3):

May be there is an easier way to automate this, but will let someone else figure it out.

Here is my attempt

```
expr = (c S ρ (Z0 Cos[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 10 L)] + 
   I c S ρ Sin[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 
        10 L)]))/(c S ρ Cos[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 
      10 L)] + I Z0 Sin[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 10 L)]);
```

Now

```
divid = Cos[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 10 L)];
Expand@(Numerator[expr]/divid)/Expand@(Denominator[expr]/divid)
```

$$
\frac{c \rho  S \text{Z0}+i c^2 \rho ^2 S^2 \tan \left(\frac{5 \pi  (2 n+1) x}{6 a+10
   L}\right)}{c \rho  S+i \text{Z0} \tan \left(\frac{5 \pi  (2 n+1) x}{6 a+10 L}\right)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

A variant of Nasser's answer

```
expr = (c S ρ (Z0 Cos[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 10 L)] + 
   I c S ρ Sin[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 
        10 L)]))/(c S ρ Cos[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 
      10 L)] + I Z0 Sin[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 10 L)]);

Divide @@ Expand[NumeratorDenominator[expr]/Cos[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 10 L)]]
```

> $$\frac{c \rho  S \text{Z0}+i c^2 \rho ^2 S^2 \tan \left(\frac{5 \pi  (2 n+1) x}{6 a+10
>    L}\right)}{c \rho  S+i \text{Z0} \tan \left(\frac{5 \pi  (2 n+1) x}{6 a+10 L}\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = (c S ρ (Z0 Cos[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 10 L)] + 
        I c S ρ Sin[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 10 L)])) /
       (c S ρ Cos[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 10 L)] + 
        I Z0 Sin[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 10 L)]);

exp2 = Cos[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 10 L)];

exp2 FullSimplify[expr / exp2]
```

> ```
> (c S ρ (Z0 + I c S ρ Tan[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 10 L)])) /
>   (c S ρ + I Z0 Tan[(5 (1 + 2 n) π x)/(6 a + 10 L)])
> ```

```
TeXForm @ %
```

$$\Large\frac{c \rho  S \text{Z0}+i c^2 \rho ^2 S^2 \tan \left(\frac{5 \pi  (2 n+1) x}{6 a+10
   L}\right)}{c \rho  S+i \text{Z0} \tan \left(\frac{5 \pi  (2 n+1) x}{6 a+10 L}\right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following will do what you want

```
expr /. {Cos[y_] :> cos[y], Sin[y_] :> Tan[y] cos[y]} // Simplify
```

in this particular simple case. If `cos[]` appears
in the simplified expression, then use `% ./ cos[y_] :> Cos[y]` to restore it.